# Algorithm Design Problem Challenge, Arrays of different length and computing the lead_time of jobs

Tags: arrays, algorithm, structure

I need some help in getting the average lead_time for the remaining jobs. Let’s suppose a1,a2,a3.....,an is the starting time of the jobs in ascending order, and b1,b2,b3,.....,bn are the ending times of the jobs in random order. Let’s suppose files (containing jobs) are transferred from one desk1 to desk2 and some of the jobs will complete before the transfer time and a lead_time will be established for the remaining jobs that were started at desk1. t1,t2,t3....,tm (ascending order) are the file transfer time from desk1 to desk2. Suppose tm>an and the file never visits the already visited desk.

My approach to solve this problem is as follows, I have checked if the job is ongoing at transfer time by taking the difference of job completion time and transfer time: pseudo code

```
start_time = {a1, a2, a3,....,an} // (ascending order)
end_time = {b1, b2, b3,....,bn} // (random order) (jobs can be or random duration)
transfer_time = {t1,t2,t3,....,tm} // (ascending order)
lead_time = 0
jobs_desk2 = 0 
for (int i = 0; i<m; i++){ 
                  if(t[i] > a[i] && b[i] > t[i] && t[i] != 0){
                                                lead_time += b[i] - t[i]
                                                jobs_desk2++
                   }
                   }
lead_time = lead_time/jobs_desk2
```

Comment: What exactly is it you need help with? Just a double check? Do you have a way of knowing which transfer goes with which start/end pair? Seems like you may have an overflow issue there...

Comment: That's the main issue, the transfer time is of files and this array is of different index i.e tm. If we consider the arrays of the same length (assumption in the question tm>an) also considering each transfer time associated with the start/end time then the above solution seems to work fine (according to my approach)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Thanks for reaching out. I was asking about a better approach to solving this problem and shared my code for any enhancements.

Comment: This problem does not appear sufficiently well-defined at present to be into code review; the next step should be better definition of the modelled scenario, since this looks like it involves too much guessing.